# How can I connect Expert EX9017F DAQ to Igor and read data from it

Tags: igor

so I've just started a project in the physics department of my uni where I need to be able to connect an Expert EX9017F DAQ to some apparatus and get a reading from it. That I can do; the problem is using Igor (version 6 I believe) to read from the DAQ.

I have the DAQ connected to Igor and I can send it commands using VDT but I need to write a programme which will automate the data collection and present it as a display. I have some coding experience in python but I have no idea how to go about this in Igor's Procedure Window. Could anyone help?

I know I'll have to do something along the lines of:
- declare DAQ as a variable
- declare a function that reads the DAQ data output
- use Igor's background repetition thing to automate it
- use ValDisplay to display the data

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Igor Pro's manual includes a guided tour for beginners. Be sure to take that first before starting coding.

If then  concrete questions come up, these can be tackled.

If possible upgrade to Igor Pro 7 this makes coding much nicer.